# Patch/put Error with FOSRestBundle and symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I need to create an REST api with symfony2. No UI, No form just a REST API.

I tried to create a simple CRUD system but I have a problem with the update.

Well,

The config.yml

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    routing_loader:
        default_format: json                            # All responses should be JSON formated
        include_format: false
    exception:
        enabled: true
```

the FeatureController :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Feature;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Request\ParamFetcher;
use Guzzle\Http\Message\Request;
use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RequestParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;

/**
 * @RouteResource("Feature", pluralize=false)
 */
class FeatureController extends FOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @param ParamFetcher $params
     * @RequestParam(name="type", requirements="[0-9]", default="0", description="type")
     * @RequestParam(name="name", requirements="[a-z]+", description="name")
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function postAction(ParamFetcher $params){
        $feature = new Feature();
        $feature
            ->setType($params->get('type'))
            ->setName($params->get('name'));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($feature);
        $em->flush();

        $view = View::create();
        $view->setStatusCode(201);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
     * @RequestParam(name="type", requirements="[0-9]", default="0", description="type")
     * @RequestParam(name="name", requirements="[a-z]+", description="name")
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function patchAction($id, ParamFetcher $paramFetcher){

        $view = View::create();
        $view
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setData([$id, 'params' => $paramFetcher->all()]);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @param ParamFetcher $paramFetcher
     * @QueryParam(name="page", requirements="\d+", description="Page of the overview.")
     * 
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getAction($id, ParamFetcher $paramFetcher){

        $view = View::create();
        $view->setData(['id' => $id, 'params' => $paramFetcher->all()])->setStatusCode(200);
        return $this->handleView($view);
    }
}
```

When i use getAction with this url /feature/5?page=55, the response is correct

```
{
  "id": "5",
  "params": {
    "page": "55"
  }
}
```

$id, ParamFetcher $paramFetcher work fine.

When I use postAction with /feature and body

```
{
  "type" : 2,
  "name" : "aze"
}
```

it works fine too.

But when I try to use patchAction with /feature/5 and body 
    {
      "type" : 5,
      "name" : "newName"
    }

The response is :

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parameter type value '' violated a constraint (This value should not be null.)"
}
```

Have you an idea ?

PS: It's the first time I use FOSRestBundle, if you have some Best practice, don't hesitate.

Comment: How are you making your calls ? With Postman ?

Comment: I remember having problems using Postman and patch requests. Try to add `_method=patch` in your querystring, using a `post` request in postman to emulate a `patch` call

Comment: Can you provide a var_dump of paramFetcher->all() in the patch function?